# How to map palo alto firewall params to strongswan's ipsec.conf

Tags: vpn, ipsec, site-to-site-vpn, strongswan

I have these configs from a partner of mine[image]

How do I match them to ipsec.conf? This is what I have currently.

```
conn %default
    ikelifetime=28800s
    keylife=3600s
    rekeymargin=3m
    keyingtries=1
    keyexchange=ikev1
    authby=psk
    type=tunnel

conn common
    left=x.x.x.x
    leftid=x.x.x.x
    leftsubnet=10.17.0.6
    leftsourceip=10.17.0.6

    right=y.y.y.y
    rightid=y.y.y.y
    ike=aes256-sha1-modp1024!
    esp=aes256-sha1!

conn conn_1
    also=common
    rightsourceip=a.a.a.a
    rightsubnet=a.a.a.a/32
    auto=start
```